# How to redefine the commands of the alertmessage package?

Tags: fancybox

How to redefine the commands of the alertmessage package?

package link: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/alertmessage

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{alertmessage}

%\renewcommand*\alertsuccess[1]{\alertmessage@panel{green}{img/alertmessage-success.png}{#1}}
 
\begin{document}

\alertinfo{hello}
\alertwarning{hello}
\alertsuccess{hello}
\alerterror{hello}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close enough, but the `@` symbol is supposed to be disabled (i.e. not a letter) in your document to ensure only developpers use internal functions. You can "reenable" the `@` symbol with `\makeatletter <your code> \makeatother`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alertmessage}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\alertsuccess[1]{%
  \alertmessage@panel{green}{example-image-a}{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\alertinfo{hello}
\alertwarning{hello}
\alertsuccess{hello}
\alerterror{hello}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Version with custom size:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alertmessage}

\makeatletter

% ALERT PANEL, copied from https://github.com/pidupuis/latex-alert-message/blob/master/alertmessage.sty
\NewDocumentCommand{\alertmessage@panelcustom}{mmmO{}}{%
  \begin{center} %
    \noindent % No indentation
    \begin{tikzpicture} %
      \node[draw=#1!80, fill=#1!20, rounded corners=5pt, inner sep=11pt]{ % Add a little bit of transparency
        $\begin{array}{l} % One-cell table
           \includegraphics[#4]{{#2}} % Alert icon
         \end{array}$ %
         \settowidth{\alertmessage@textlength}{{#3}} %
         \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\alertmessage@textlength > 400pt}}{ % If text is more than 400pt
           \parbox{340pt}{{#3}} % Box which handles paragraphs, limited to 10cm
         }{ % Else
           \makebox{}{{#3}} % Box which adapts itself to the text length
         } %
      }; %
    \end{tikzpicture} %
  \end{center} %
  \par % Get back the indentation
}%

\renewcommand*\alertsuccess[1]{%
  \alertmessage@panelcustom{green}{example-image-a}{#1}[width=6mm]%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\alertinfo{hello}
\alertwarning{hello}
\alertsuccess{hello}
\alerterror{hello}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2**
Version which patch directly the package. The above is certainly simpler, but here is for the fun:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alertmessage}

\makeatletter
% let's patch
\NewCommandCopy\originalalertmessage@panel\alertmessage@panel
\xpatchparametertext\originalalertmessage@panel{\#1\#2\#3}{\cP\#1\cP\#2\cP\#3\cP\#4}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\originalalertmessage@panel}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5,#4]}{}{}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\alertmessage@panel}{mmmO{}}{%
  \originalalertmessage@panel{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\renewcommand*\alertsuccess[1]{%
  \alertmessage@panel{green}{example-image-a}{#1}[width=6mm]%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\alertinfo{hello}
\alertwarning{hello}
\alertsuccess{hello}
\alerterror{hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you adjust the image dimensions? I can from the .dtx file, But I want to use direct code in the preamble.

Comment: I don't think you can directly, the code is only applying "scale=0.5". If you want to apply the same scale to all pictures, you could try to patch the command using `patchcmd` from etoolbox, however it will break the other `\alertinfo`. And I'm not sure if you can add an argument when patching... I asked the question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617690 So I think the easier is simply to copy/paste the code and change it to your needs. See my edit.

Comment: See edit with a patched version, thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617690/patch-command-by-adding-new-optional-arguments-and-turn-newcommand-into-ne