# Patch command by adding new (optional) arguments (and turn `newcommand` into `NewDocumentCommand`)

Tags: xparse, patching, xpatch

In a package, I'd like to customize an existing macro by adding an optional argument to control the size of an image. However, I've no idea how to patch a command to add arguments. Ideally I'd love to add the argument at the end (otherwise I'll need to patch all the function to change the `#1` into `#2`), and I particularly like the way `NewDocumentCommand` works...

So is it possible to patch `\newcommand*\hello[1]{...}` into `\NewDocumentCommand{\hello}{mo}{...}`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\hello[1]{%
  Hello #1.
}

% Goal: patch into:
% \NewDocumentCommand{\hello}{mo}{%
%   Hello #1\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{ and #2}.
% }


\begin{document}
\hello{Bob}
% I want this to work as well:
% \hello{Bob}[Alice]
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**
I tried to apply the egreg's answer on this more practical example [How to redefine the commands of the alertmessage package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/617331/how-to-redefine-the-commands-of-the-alertmessage-package/617336) however the `\NewCommandCopy\originalalertmessage@panel\alertmessage@panel` gives an error `Missing \begin{document}.`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alertmessage}

% let's patch
\NewCommandCopy\originalalertmessage@panel\alertmessage@panel
\xpatchparametertext\originalalertmessage@panel{\#1\#2\#3}{\cP\#1\cP\#2\cP\#3\cP\#4}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\originalalertmessage@panel}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5,#4]}{}{}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\alertmessage@panel}{mmmO{}}{%
  \originalalertmessage@panel{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}

\renewcommand*\alertsuccess[1]{%
  \alertmessage@panelcustom{green}{example-image-a}{#1}[width=6mm]%
}%

\begin{document}


\alertinfo{hello}
\alertwarning{hello}
\alertsuccess{hello}
\alerterror{hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: just `\NewCommandCopy\hello\oldhello`  then `\RenewDocumentCommand{\hello}{mo}{\oldhello{#1}\If...}` except that if you really mean to remove the trailing `. ` added by the original `#1` then it will be far simpler to just redefine the command rather than using the old definition at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\NewCommandCopy`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer as I wrote?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle exactly ;-)

Comment: You need `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`; and also to type `\alertmessage@panel` instead of `\alertmessage@panelcustom`. But it's ***much*** simpler to rewrite the whole package.

Comment: Oh stupid me, I removed them by mistake. Now it's working, thanks a lot! And yes, I definitely agree that it's simpler to rewrite the whole package. But just wanted to practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `regexpatch` that allows to modify the number of arguments to `\hello`.

But I don't think it's a good approach.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{regexpatch}

\newcommand*\hello[1]{%
  Hello #1.
}

% let's patch
\NewCommandCopy\originalhello\hello
\xpatchparametertext\originalhello{\#1}{\cP\#1\cP\#2}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\originalhello}{.}{\IfValueT{#2}{ and #2}.}{}{}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\hello}{mo}{%
  \originalhello{#1}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}

\hello{Bob}

\hello{Bob}[Alice]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note. `\cP` is not really necessary with an up-to-date LaTeX, but I left it there for greater safety.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however I get `ERROR: Illegal parameter number in definition of \originalhello.` on line `\xpatchparametertext\originalhello{\#1}{\#1\#2}{}{}`

Comment: @tobiasBora Do you? I don't, but then you're running an older version of LaTeX. Change `{\#1\#2}` into `{\cP\#1\cP\#2}`

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, how would the command be updated if the command had multiples and/or optional parameters?

Comment: @tobiasBora I can't answer in this generality. On the other hand, too many argument are not recommended if you want an easy user interface.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to put a more practical usecase in edit, but it fails directly on `\NewCommandCopy\originalalertmessage@panel\alertmessage@panel` with an error `Missing \begin{document}.`.